# Working around IP Conflicts with ARP meddling or custom TCP/IP stack

Tags: ethernet, arp

Slightly interesting conundrum, I have a network of 15-20 embedded devices that are effectively hard coded with the same static IP address, but they all have different MAC ID's.  I need to address them individually in order to configure them remotely, and plug/unplugging them is not a sustainable solution.

While I have root access to the devices, I cannot set their IP's to unique addresses beforehand, I can however reconfigure it for the session and have it reset on power cycle, but this requires being able to address them over TCP/IP to begin with.

Ideally what I would like to do is enumerate all the MAC's on the network (assume guaranteed only this embedded device) and either modify my ARP table or reach in and modify ethernet packet headers at a repeater (say a raspberry running a modified IP stack). Ideally this hack would only need to be live long enough to connect to the device and set its ip to a unique address. I guess the essence of what I want to do is replace the ARP service with a custom resolution protocol.

I am versed in kernel, low level, and driver development, but with ethernet above Level 2 on OSI I am a little lost. What implications would this kind of meddling have on higher level protocols? Can I simply replace the ARP daemon on linux to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I don't know about enumerating the devices, but if I understand correctly, hard coding the mac address into the arp table would force requests for that IP to the desired machine - and the upper layers of the OSI model really don't care as long as the lower levels are happy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the devices are on the same subnet as the device you wish to do this from, it should be possible to "steer" the IP packets but writing your own ethernet packets with the correct MAC and IP addresses. The responses will be destined for your machine, but you'll likely have to pick them up and process them yourself as the OS's system maybe not be able to sort them out correctly.

To do this, you'll need:

- a rough understanding of what data ethernet, IP, and TCP packets consist of (google should help with this; [this](http://www.laneye.com/network/how-network-works/mac-address-and-ip-address-relationship.htm) gives an overview of the overall packet structure)
- a way to assemble them and get them on the wire ([this](https://austinmarton.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/sending-raw-ethernet-packets-from-a-specific-interface-in-c-on-linux/) describes the basics)
- a way to receive response packets ([this](https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/2862515) should help with that)
- and a way to assemble the received packets into something useful (since you're receiving raw ethernet packets, the TCP stream won't be assembled or ordered for you, you'll need to buffer and assemble the data yourself as well as deal with the other pieces of the TCP protocol; once you've got the above items working, you should know enough about TCP streams to do this)

[Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) is a tool for sniffing networks and has a lot of detail that can help you understand what goes on in the network, what's in the packets so you can match it up with what you learn, and help you debug your software.